# Git merge giving unexpected results

Tags: git, git-merge

We're trying to merge two Git branches.

[This](https://github.com/gnosis/dutch-exchange/commit/7f46cd43102b1f63bf0a5416a376b7c880313b1d) is the merge commit.

[This](https://github.com/gnosis/dutch-exchange/blob/2c0135217daa3fefbbc7e73a6ee94682c33a9b81/contracts/DutchExchange.sol#L30) is the file link of the source commit.
[This](https://github.com/gnosis/dutch-exchange/blob/db30386422f648a3e3382f5648e987bfc178d93d/contracts/DutchExchange.sol#L32) is the file link of the target commit.

Based on the commit graph: [link](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/MhuhZYh1ZBvEHaEtINQLtM4vQ3wJhZX-7ljkPZkaZpkgsvkoJkEFrmu_jvGtGxTVa7-vPGsGuw67pQ=w2880-h1606-rw)

[image: commit graph]

the closes common ancestor is commit 01886ab, right? Well it one has [the following](https://github.com/gnosis/dutch-exchange/blob/01886aba2c30ac6f5c8e312df458c9af62851992/contracts/DutchExchange.sol#L30) version of the file.

My understanding of git merge is that merging "A" into "B" with base "A" should output "B". Based on that, I have problems with the comments: "The following two/three mappings are symmetrical..." (lines 30/31/32).

In the base file, there is "three". The source file has "two" and the target "three". According to my understanding, it should merge to "two".

It merged to "three" ([merge file](https://github.com/gnosis/dutch-exchange/blob/7f46cd43102b1f63bf0a5416a376b7c880313b1d/contracts/DutchExchange.sol#L31)).

Thank you!!

Comment: You don't merge commits, you merge branches.

Comment: @choroba Thanks for the comment. I have edited the first line. Any idea what I'm missing, though?

Comment: @choroba: actually, you *do* merge commits: `git merge foobranch` means: *Look up the commit hash to which `foobranch` points. Look up commit `HEAD`. Find the merge base of these commits. Merge using the base as the base commit, `HEAD` as the current or local head, and the commit to which `foobranch` points as the remote head.* If (1) a merge is required and (2) this merge-as-a-verb all goes well, `git merge` makes (3) a new commit that is a *merge commit* (merge as an adjective/noun), on the current branch as usual, but with each of the two heads as its two parents.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran this merge locally I got a merge conflict.  The conflict was because in commit `6d8450ab64821a280aa0e2d20c42e4929d028812`, which is an ancestor of `db30386422f648a3e3382f5648e987bfc178d93d`, you added whitespace above the line `The following...`; and in commit `333d343af1ac436eff598231957e9705e4121dab`, an ancestor of `2c0135217daa3fefbbc7e73a6ee94682c33a9b81`, you changed `three` to `two`.  Furthermore, if you checkout the merge commit `7f46cd43102b1f63bf0a5416a376b7c880313b1d` and run `git blame contracts/DutchExchange.sol`, you'll see on line 32 that the merge commit introduced a newline.  So to answer your question, it looks like it merged to three because that's how you resolved the merge conflict.